# Best way of using Twitter Digits with Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, twitter-digits

I have a React-Native app that uses Twitter Digits to authenticate.
After I auth, I get the response object of the auth 1.0 headers:

```
Object {X-Auth-Service-Provider: "https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json", X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization: "OAuth ..."}
```

Does someone knows how to use these credentials to authenticate with firebase?